# how can i get nested data from a JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(example)

Tags: c#

Using the example code works correctly to get the non-nested data from "issues", how can I get the nested data from "issues"? In the picture you can see which data we are talking about.

Code:

```
try
{
   var dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(strResponseValue);
   string records = dynObj["issues"].ToString();
   JArray a = JArray.Parse(records);
   List<string> colNames = new List<string>() {"expand", "key", "id", 
   "self" };

   string headerRow = "";
   foreach (string colName in colNames)
   {
      headerRow += "\"" + colName + "\";";
   }
   headerRow = headerRow.TrimEnd(';');
   headerRow += "\n";

   string dataRows = "";
   foreach (var record in a)
   {
      string thisRecord = "";
      foreach (string colName in colNames)
      {
         thisRecord += "\"" + record[colName] + "\";";
      }
      thisRecord = thisRecord.TrimEnd(';');
      thisRecord += "\n";
      dataRows += thisRecord;
   }
   csvData = headerRow + dataRows;

   Console.WriteLine("\ncsvData:");
   Console.WriteLine(csvData);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ 
   Console.WriteLine("Exeption Error" + ex.ToString()); 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `json` is complex, you can let visual studio do the job.

1. Copy the json content
2. Use Edit/Paste Special - **Paste JSON As Classes**
3. Use the generated Class to deserialize your json content.

For instance deserialize to `MyClass` (from [.Net Fundumentals - JSON Serialize/Deserialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#how-to-read-json-as-net-objects-deserialize)):

```
MyClass? myclass = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(jsonString);
```